# Dimensions of similar matrices prove problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

So the question asks:

Let A and B be two similar n × n matrices, and let S be the invertible matrix testifying this similarity (that is, $A = SBS^{−1}$). Denote by $T_A$ and $T_B$ the linear transformations associated to the matrices A and B, respectively (this is, $T_A$(**x**) = A**x** and $T_B$(**x**) = B**x**).

(a) Prove that if **x** $∈ ker(T_B)$ then S**x** ∈ $ker(T_A)$.

(b) Prove that $dim(ker(T_A)) = dim(ker(T_B))$ [Hint: show that if { **x**1, . . . , 
**x**n} is a basis of $ker(T_B),$ then the set {S**x**1, . . . , S**x**n} is a basis of $ker(T_A)$].

So so far  I have:

(a)

For part a,

Since **x** $∈ ker(T_B)$, by the defnition of kernel, B**x** = **0**

Need to prove: S**x** ∈ $ker(T_A)$ which is A(S**x**) = **0**

Since $A = SBS^{−1}$, then $B = S^{−1}AS$

So  B**x** = $S^{−1}AS$**x** = **0**,

then $S^{−1}(AS$**x**) = **0**

Since S is the invertible matrix so $S ≠ 0$

then $(AS$**x**) = **0**,

$A(S$**x**) = **0**

By the definition of the kernel, S**x** ∈ $ker(T_A)$ proved.

(b)

For part b,

Suppose { **x**1, . . . , **x**n} is a basis of $ker(T_B)$, then $B$**x**1+$B$**x**2+...+ $B$**x**n =**0**

Need to prove that {S**x**1, . . . , S**x**n} is a basis of $ker(T_A)$, which is $A$S**x**1+$A$S**x**2+...+ $A$S**x**n = **0**

Since $B = S^{−1}AS$,

Then $S^{−1}AS$**x**1+$S^{−1}AS$**x**2+...+ $S^{−1}AS$**x**n =**0**

Multiply both sides by $S$,

$S$$S^{−1}AS$**x**1+$S$$S^{−1}AS$**x**2+...+ $S$$S^{−1}AS$**x**n =$S$**0**,

then $A$S**x**1+$A$S**x**2+...+ $A$S**x**n = **0**

By the definitions of the kernel and basis, {S**x**1, . . . , S**x**n} is a basis of $ker(T_A)$ proved.

By the definitions of dimension, $dim(ker(T_A)) = n, dim(ker(T_B))$ =n

So $dim(ker(T_A)) = dim(ker(T_B))$ proved

Does my solution look right? Especially for part b, is my proof for the {S**x**1, . . . , S**x**n} is a basis of $ker(T_A)$ part look solid?

Answer (score 0):

Another proof: note that two similar matrix$A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial. The eigenspace associated to eigenvalue $0$ that is equal to $\ker$ of a linear transformation doesn't dipende by choice of a basis but by linear map